# Swift - generating image thumbnail from a local video

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avasset, avurlasset

I'm trying to create a Thumbnail image from a video:

```
    func getImageFromUrl(url:URL) -> UIImage?{
    print(url)
    let video = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let thumbnailGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: video)

        do
        {
            let cgImage = try thumbnailGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
            let UiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return UiImage
        }
        catch
        { print(error) }
    return nil
}
```

and I'm getting this Error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x2804c50b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}}

HELP ANYONE ?

Answer (score 1):

That error tells us that this is an HTTP, not local issue. The [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/code/serverincorrectlyconfigured) says "This error might indicate that the HTTP server doesn’t support byte range requests." and or that "The HTTP server sending the media resource is not configured as expected." Check to make sure the HTTP server is configured properly and allows this type of query.

Comment: it's from a local URL - it's a video that was taken from the camera. 
the problem is probably I tried to approach the file before it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a server issue as peer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/code/serverincorrectlyconfigured)

```
case serverIncorrectlyConfigured = -11850
```

*This error might indicate that the server doesn’t support byte-range requests.*

You can try this video URL to check if your code actually works:

```
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
```

Will you be able to share the video URL to check?

Comment: it's from a local URL - it's a video that was taken from the camera.

Comment: Is it for any video? did you try another format?

Comment: mp4.  I think The problem was that I tried to read the file before it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `copyCGImage` is Deprecated

Try using [image(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/3930658-image) instead.